# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I tried getting the firebase binds to work with knockoutjs but couldn't get them working so i'm trying a little test with angularjs. So I downloaded angularjs and i'm trying to just get some data in/out. So right now I have this in my app.js:

```
/* Controllers */

angular.module('MyCtrl3', ['$scope', 'angularFire'])
.controller ("MyCtrl3", function ($scope, angularFire) {
$scope.addMsg = function ($scope, angularFire) {
    var url = 'https://kingpinapp.firebaseio.com/msgs';
    var promise = angularFire(url, $scope, 'msgs', []);
    $scope.msgs.push({name: "Firebase", desc: "is awesome!"});

}
});
```

and then my html is just:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My AngularJS App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl3">

<button ng-click="addMsg()">Add</button>
</div>

<!-- bunch of scripts -->
</body>
</html>
```

just trying to get the add button to push to firebase. I get this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined.
Added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NHaZz/5/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle out of it?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with angular but are you sure that your URL is returning valid data? Maybe $scope.msgs isn't being properly initialized if the return from server is null or unexpected somehow? I would throw a console log in your promise callback and see what '$scope' and '$scope.msgs' look like when the promise is returned. Either that or you need to manually/explicitly initialize $scope.msgs (I have no idea if Angular or whatever plugins you're using are supposed to take care of this themselves)

Comment: From the looks of it, you did not initialize $scope.msgs to an empty array in your controller. Try that at the beginning of MyCtrl3.

Comment: Updated code to simplify the problem. Also uploaded a jsfiddle.

Comment: Could you try some of the things @JBland and I suggested above and report back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularFire returns a promise, therefore you cannot manipulate the array until the promise has been fulfilled. You can do this with the `then` function, as follows:

```js
angular.module('MyCtrl3', ['$scope', 'angularFire'])
.controller ("MyCtrl3", function ($scope, angularFire) {
  var url = 'https://kingpinapp.firebaseio.com/msgs';
  var promise = angularFire(url, $scope, 'msgs', []);
  promise.then(function() {
    $scope.addMsg = function ($scope, angularFire) {
      $scope.msgs.push({name: "Firebase", desc: "is awesome!"});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: still have these:Error: Argument 'MyCtrl3' is not a function, got undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Comment: Your module and controller have the same name (Change angular.module's first argument to something else and set ng-app to that name in the HTML).

Comment: Hm ok getting closer. After updating the module to a different name and adding it to the html. I get: Uncaught Error: No module: $scope. And this one is still present: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Comment: You also haven't defined Firebase as a dependency to your module. Here's a fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/DR4r9/10/

Answer (score 2):

AngularFire 0.3.0 seems to have changed a little, so you can't just send a url using angularFire, you need to provide:

```
new Firebase("example-url-to-your-firebase.com");
```

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/DR4r9/14/