# What is the equivalent of firebaseRef.push() with angularfire?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

In the following non-angularfire pseudo-code I would expect to have firebase generate a key for the new data being pushed in.

```
var ref = Firebase(...);
var newref = ref.push({"blah":"blah"});
var autoKey = newref.name();
```

I try to do the same thing through angularfire with a bound model but it just gives me errors about the object not having a `push()` method, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283747/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-push-of-undefined). He got it working when the data type was an array.

How do I get the nice behaviour I've seen in regular Firebase (non-angularFire) with automatic keys for objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use an Object and have auto-generated keys, use the `add` method on a `angularFireCollection`. For example:

```js
function ExampleController($scope, angularFireCollection) {
  var url = 'https://angularFireExample.firebaseio-demo.com/';
  $scope.examples = angularFireCollection(url);
  $scope.addExample = function(ex) {
    $scope.examples.add(ex);
  };
}
```

Comment: Ah, that sounds promising, I'll try it tonight. Is there an API reference for angularFire other than looking at the code?

Comment: For the record, each item that ends up in `$scope.examples` above gets the extra members `$ref`, `$id` and `$index` added as they are pulled out of Firebase. See the `angularFireItem` class defined in  [angularFire.js](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/gh-pages/angularFire.js).

Comment: Will `$scope.examples` be synchronize with firebase data?